# how to download images that has protected links with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a website and download all the images in it, but all the links there are protected with Cloudflare; when I try to get the picture `src` and open it, I get `Error 1020. Access denied.`

I tried the following:

```
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath(Whole_img_xpath)
src = img.get_attribute('src')
with open(f'fileName.jpg', 'wb') as file:
  file.write(requests.get(src).content)
```

this one only create an empty image file; it can't write anything to it

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, f'fileName.jpg')
```

this one failed too: `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

```
this 
img.screenshot(f'fileName.png')

and this
with open(f'fileName.jpg', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(img.screenshot_as_png)
```

kind of work but both of them only take half of any image; I don't know why, but it never gets the full resolution of any image

---

all I want is a way to download the images; they're a way to `right-click save image as`
other than complex code, it to send_keys right-click ...

I am running out of things to try, and `I am once again asking for your support (. ❛ ᴗ ❛.)

Comment: Sounds very hopeless. Your answer is built very bad for sure. Better use wget util in linux terminal :)

Comment: try adding referrer to your request header... (you may also need authentication added)  it's pretty common for websites to check the referrer to prevent "deep links".  So set the referrer to the site's domain.

Comment: @pcalkins 
can you explain more 
or maybe show me how its done